# Elegant Way to Get the Minimum of More than One Column of a Data Frame and Their Corresponding Values in Another Column

Tags: r

Given a data frame `df`, I want a new data frame that will keep the minimum values of columns `Y` and `Z` in a column and their corresponding values on the `X` column in another column using `R`.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
                "X  Y  Z
              1  2  3  1.4
              2  4  5  1.7
              3  6  7  1.2
              4  8  9  2.1
              5 10 11  3.2",
              header = TRUE)
```

**Trial**

Here is what I have tried using `R` which is labour intensive.

```
data.frame(
  x_min = c(df[df$Y == min(df[,"Y"]), "X"], df[df$Z == min(df[,"Z"]), "X"]),
  min_Y_Z = c(min(df[,"Y"]), min(df[,"Z"]))
  )
```

I know that `apply(df, 2, min)` will only work if I am to find the minimum of each and every column in the data frame, so no need to look toward the `apply()` family function.

**The Result**

```
  x_min min_Y_Z
1     2     3.0
2     6     1.2
```

**What I Want**

I want an `R`-elegant way to write the same solution. I will not mind using packages in `R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you could use `lapply`. This version is similar to your current method, but does not rely on the explicit column names as much, since "Y" and "Z" are abstracted by `lapply`. This version also places the original column names in the rownames.

```
lst <- lapply(df[c('Y', 'Z')], function(i) {
  
  min_index <- which.min(i)
  return(data.frame(x_min = df$X[min_index], min_Y_Z = i[min_index]))
  
})

result <- do.call(rbind, lst)

  x_min min_Y_Z
Y     2     3.0
Z     6     1.2
```

Or another **tidyverse** solution:

```
result <- df %>% 
  summarize(across(c(Y, Z), which.min)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = 'idx') %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    x_min = df[['X']][idx],
    min_Y_Z = df[[name]][idx]
  ) %>% 
  select(-name, -idx)

  x_min min_Y_Z
  <int>   <dbl>
1     2     3  
2     6     1.2
```

Comment: I actually want the result of your first method to be in a data frame and not a list.

Comment: The final line: `result <- do.call(rbind, lst)` converts the list to a data frame, which is the output you see in that section.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is using the `subset()` and `mutate()` functions from the tidyverse package:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_new <- df %>% 
  subset(Y == min(Y) | Z == min(Z)) %>%
  mutate(min_Y_Z = c(min(Y), min(Z)))
```

This gives you this output:

```
X Y   Z min_Y_Z
1 2 3 1.4     3.0
3 6 7 1.2     1.2
```

If needed, removing the old 'Y' and 'Z' columns is pretty simple to do as well.

Comment: Nice +1! Note that `subset()` is actually from base R. The `tidyverse`, or more accurately `dplyr`, equivalent is `filter()` :)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. There's so many different functions in tidyverse I forget what belongs and what doesn't!